# I need to make a this button go down 35px into the following div (overlap)

Tags: html, css

I want to make the download button (#bluebutton) go down about 35 px into the following div to give the effect of overlapping the two divs (clickable) being in the middle(closer to the social buttons).. How can I accomplish this? I want a cleanest way possible. Thank you so much for your help. I can supply more pics if needed. a fiddle is very very appreciated =)

[image: This is how it currently looks with some of the mark up on the side]

Comment: Can you include the markup with the relevant style? Difficult to tell you how to style it without it.

Comment: what's the style of the div that's below your button?

Comment: just view source on the site that i supplied

Comment: @user3105072 I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hGEKw) with the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put this css to your blue button div

```
 #bluebutton {
   width: 60%;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #05afcd;
   border: 1.5px solid #505050;
   margin: auto;
   height: 70px;
   font-size: 36px;
   margin-bottom: -35px;
   z-index: 9999;
   position: relative;  /*** add position relative *******/
   zoom: 1;    /*** add zoom:1 for ie old browsers  *******/
 }
```

here is demo fiddle of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/FM99D/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
#bluebutton {
    margin-bottom: -35px;
}
```

If you have any issues with being able to click it in the gray background area..

just add

```
#bluebutton {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: check out http://www.tumster.com for full mark up. because of the way i have it the z index dosent effect it

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hGEKw) with the relevant parts from your code.

On it I have done the following modification on the styles (marked with comments):

```
#bluebutton
{
 width: 60%;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #05afcd;
 border: 1.5px solid #505050;
 margin: auto;
 height: 70px;
 font-size: 36px;
 position: relative; /*<---*/
 top: 35px; /*<---*/
}
```

You can see it after the modification at this [new CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCmvL).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle I made for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/B9UvD/1/

Basicly, what you need to is to take the box from its natural flow. You do this by applying this to your #bluebutton:

```
position: relative; 
top: 20px;
```

(btw, try to name the button to something more universal and descriptable. You don't know if you want the blue button to be red or something in the future. #download-button could be a better name)